# How to solve the "Intervention Slow network is detected." error in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have been getting the following error:

**"[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:19006/fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf"**

While researching this error I have read a lot of people recommending to disable the error or just straight up ignore it, but since I have been getting this error the refresh time has increased substantially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple instances running and hadn't restarted my PC in a while. After a restart it was fixed and back to loading almost instantly...